# Store username in database while doing rest or soap api calls from application A to application B in Java Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-security

I have two applications, in first application say A user login by username and password. I get logged in username by using spring authentication obejct in application A. Application A is making rest or soap api calls to application B. I am passing username from A to B  application by adding username in header of rest or soap calls. Application B is making database calls, doing CRUD on SQL database. I want to save that username in updated by, modified by fields. I used bean to store username but when multiple users are using application it's getting overwritten. How this can be achieved? Thank you

In the following interceptor userSync will save my current logged in username, usernameGetter will be used to get current logged in username from http request. userSync and usernameGetter are singleton beans.

```
public class RequestInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {



private DomainUserSynchronizer userSynchronizer;

@Autowired
UsernameGetter usernameGetter;

@Autowired
private UserSynchronizer userSync;

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RequestInterceptor.class);



@Override
public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1, Object arg2, Exception arg3)
        throws Exception {

    LOGGER.info("Inside after completion");
}

@Override
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView)
        throws Exception {

    // do nothing

}

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
        throws Exception {

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    // Enumeration e = (Enumeration) (session.getAttributeNames());

     //session.getAttribute("an");
     //session.getAttribute("MYSPEAK_SESSION_HASH");



    String username = usernameGetter.getUsernameFromSession(request);
    if(username!=null && !username.isEmpty()){
        LOGGER.info("Found username in request: "+ username);
        LOGGER.info("Setting username in userSynchronizer: "+ username);
        userSync.getCurrentUser().setName(username);
    }
    else{
        LOGGER.info(" Username not found in request: ");
        LOGGER.info("Setting default username in userSynchronizer: "+ userSync.getCurrentUser().getName());

    }   

    return true;
}

public DomainUserSynchronizer getUserSynchronizer() {
    return userSynchronizer;
}

public void setUserSynchronizer(DomainUserSynchronizer userSynchronizer) {
    this.userSynchronizer = userSynchronizer;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your issue is in the scope of the beans you've declared through Spring: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html

I would recommend you to check that all calls go through a max level of Request scope.

Another point to tackle in your issue is to confirm/rollback the transaction per each call by rest/soap you do. It could be possible that you're overwritting the entity of database without committing it.

To avoid also the overrides in the updates I would suggest to add a logging table in which you keep track of all modifications and you can only do inserts on it (immutable/audit rows)

Comment: Thank you Antonio. I am using interceptor for intercepting every request to server. Taking out username from header of request and setting it in a bean for future use, problem is when multiple users are making requests at the same time that bean getting overwritten by any other user's username. That will save wrong information in database by saving other user's name.

Comment: Yes, that's why I commented to check the scope of the beans. Maybe you're using a session bean that gets overwriten all the time by the interceptor. 
Can you post some code or configuration?

Comment: I have edited my question with code. Can you suggest me based on code? Thank you

Comment: I got solution by making userSync bean request scope.

Comment: Can you then please mark my answer as accepted? That's why I recommended Request scope, I thought the issue was about it :)
Happy I could help!